# How to format UITextField with NSNumberFormatter?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter, uitextposition

Hope this helps others, since I haven't seen any similar post on the web that shows how to format a text field using `NSNumberFormatter` but at the same time keep the `UITextField` cursor position to where it should naturally be. Those, because after formatting, the `NSString` from inside the `UITextField` and setting it back to the `field` you end up with the cursor placed an the end of the `field`. 
Also it will be nice to convert it to Swift for those that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

And here is my answer to the issue, I am using a UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad, but also it will work fine with a UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, if other keyboard types are used, feel free to add a regex before using the next code:

```
- (int)getCharOccurencies:(NSString *)character inString:(NSString *)string{

    NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[string length]];
    for (int i=0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [string characterAtIndex:i]];
        [characters addObject:ichar];
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (NSString *ichar in characters) {
        if ([ichar isEqualToString:character]) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;

}

- (void)selectTextForInput:(UITextField *)input atRange:(NSRange)range {
    UITextPosition *start = [input positionFromPosition:[input beginningOfDocument]
                                                 offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [input positionFromPosition:start
                                               offset:range.length];
    [input setSelectedTextRange:[input textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSString *charUsedToFormat = @",";

    NSMutableString *textString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textField text]];
    [textField setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

    if ([string isEqualToString:charUsedToFormat]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if ([[textString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string] length] == 0) {
        textField.text = @"";
        [self selectTextForInput:textField atRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *replacebleString = [textString substringWithRange:range];

    if (string.length == 0 && [replacebleString isEqualToString:charUsedToFormat]) {

        NSRange newRange = NSMakeRange( range.location - 1, range.length);
        range = newRange;
        textString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:newRange withString:string]];
    }else{
         textString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
    }


    int commmaCountBefore = [self getCharOccurencies:charUsedToFormat inString:textString];

    textString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[textString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:charUsedToFormat withString:@""]];
    NSNumber *firstNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[textString doubleValue]];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    //just in case
    [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [formatter setGroupingSeparator:charUsedToFormat];
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@""];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    textString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[formatter stringForObjectValue:firstNumber]];
    textField.text = textString;

    int commmaCountAfter = [self getCharOccurencies:charUsedToFormat inString:textString];
    int commaDif = commmaCountAfter - commmaCountBefore;


    int cursorPossition = (int)range.location + (int)string.length + commaDif;

    //set cursor position
    NSLog(@"cursorPossition: %d", cursorPossition);


    [self selectTextForInput:textField atRange:NSMakeRange(cursorPossition, 0)];

    return NO;

}
```